# Splitting a string for printing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to print some headers around some strings, you can see it working fine here, although if the string is really long I need to split it then print a much longer header.

```
+===================================================+
| Running: sdt_test                                 |
| Skipping:inquiry/"Inq VPD C0" mem/"Maint In Cmnd" |
+===================================================+
sh: /net/flanders/export/ws/ned/proto/bin/sdt_test: No such file or directory
+=====================+
| Running: dtd_tester |
+=====================+
sh: /net/flanders/export/ws/ned/proto/bin/dtd_tester: No such file or directory
+===============+
| Running: pssm |
+===============+
sh: /net/flanders/export/ws/ned/proto/bin/pssm: No such file or directory
+==============+
| Running: psm |
+==============+
sh: /net/flanders/export/ws/ned/proto/bin/psm: No such file or directory
+===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================+
| Running: ssm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| Skipping:"Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_3 Multi Sequence" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_2 Steady State" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_4 Test Abort" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_6 Test extend" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_9 exceptions" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_11 failed io" |
+===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================+
```

It appears fine there, although the SSM test, I would like split up on a certain amount of characters, maybe 100 or just on the whitespace between suites.

I'm really not too sure on how to do this, this is the code that currently does it.

```
#calculate lengths to make sure header is correct length
        l1 = len(x)
        l2 = len(y)
        skip = False
        if 'disable=' in test and 'disable="*"' not in test:
            skip = True
        #if entire test suite is to be disabled or not run
        if disable:
            headerBreak ="+" + "="*(l1+12) + "+"
            print headerBreak
            print "| Skipping: %s |" % x
        #if the test suite will be executed
        else:
            if skip == False:
                l2 = 0
            headerBreak =  "+" + "="*(max(l1,l2)+11) + "+"
            print headerBreak
            print "| Running: %s" % x, ' '*(l2-l1)+ '|'
            #if some suites are disabled but some are still running
            if skip:
               print "| Skipping:%s |" % y
        print headerBreak
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module to simplify this

For example if the max width was 44

```
>>> max_width = 44
>>> header='''Skipping:"Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_3 Multi Sequence" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_2 Steady State" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_4 Test Abort" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_6 Test extend" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_9 exceptions" "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_11 failed io"'''
>>> h = ["Running: ssm"] + textwrap.wrap(header, width=max_width-4)
>>> maxh = len(max(h, key=len))
>>> print "+="  + "="*maxh + "=+"
+==========================================+
>>> for i in h:
...     print "| " + i.ljust(maxh) + " |"... 
| Running: ssm                             |
| Skipping:"Secondary Subset Manager       |
| Tests"/"SSSM_3 Multi Sequence"           |
| "Secondary Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_2 |
| Steady State" "Secondary Subset Manager  |
| Tests"/"SSSM_4 Test Abort" "Secondary    |
| Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_6 Test       |
| extend" "Secondary Subset Manager        |
| Tests"/"SSSM_9 exceptions" "Secondary    |
| Subset Manager Tests"/"SSSM_11 failed    |
| io"                                      |
>>> print "+="  + "="*maxh + "=+"
+==========================================+
```

Comment: This is very useful, but I am finding it exceptionally hard to translate this into my actual code.